# How works email preview in Outlook?

Tags: .net, outlook, vsto

I am currently working on a VSTO project and looking to understand how Outlook displays the "peek preview" in the explorer view..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PufF1.png)

Apparently, it is not always a fixed size, sometimes it goes through newlines (concat), sometimes not...

Maybe Outlook can generate this text preview on demand via VSTO ? like msg.body.GetPreview() or a header ?

Thanks for any info on this

NB: Trying to get a similar preview to outlook native preview